# Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided

Tags: sql-server

Windows service with logon as `domian\user1`
Added login to instance with this user, mapped to databases needed.
Connection from service is using windows auth

When it runs, I get this error :

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user domian\user1

Ive tried several things such as net use with the credentials, I know the password is correct.
Checked the spelling, the login matches.

What else?

**[ update ]**

Looking at the sql log, I see the same thing
*Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided*

Its as if this login doesnt exist on the instance

Comment: SQL Server login failure messages sent to the client are intentionally vague for security reasons. Look at the SQL Server Security Audit log - it will contain the real reason for the login failure: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1735/auditing-failed-logins-in-sql-server/

Comment: If you created a domain login, then you don't pass the password; which implies you're trying to pass domain credentials as SQL Authentication credentials.

Comment: Do you mean `DOMAIN1` instead of `DOMIAN1`?

Comment: yes, domain\user1 (just dummied up for public consumption).  connection stread is specified with integrated security, and the connection is attempted but its as oif SQL cant see this login

Comment: Have you enabled remote connections?

Comment: Yes, there are other logins that are being used the same way

Comment: Please post your full connection-string. I suspect that you're using a Windows Username and Password in the connection-string (which won't work anyway) and you're not using `Integrated Security=SSPI` or `Trusted_Connection=True`. See https://www.connectionstrings.com for more information and good examples.